# Locking Excel file from viewing, and view only with password

Tags: php, laravel

I could not find anywhere an option to lock exported Excel files with Laravel-Excel (Or PhpSpreadsheet).

My entire website is already using Laravel-Excel for exports. Is there any way to be able to password-protect these exported Excel files somehow? Really couldn't find any viable way to do it.

Comment: Are those files exported after visiting a URL (endpoint) on your web app ? If yes why not add basic auth to those endpoints?

Comment: There’s two basic types of protection you can have on a spreadsheet, protection from viewing and protection from editing, and PhpSpreadsheet only offers the [latter](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-security-on-a-spreadsheet). This [package](https://github.com/nick322/secure-spreadsheet) allegedly does the former but I've never tried it so I can give an opinion on it.